# Why don't heatseekers lock on to low flying vehicles?

Tags: battlefield-4

Whenever I try to lock on to a low-flying attack or scout helicopter with heatseekers, it doesn't work. I know in Battlefield 3 there was an upgrade called "Below Radar" which gave helicopters this property. However, I haven't seen this ability in the Battlefied 4 progression for any air vehicles. Is this upgrade just given for free to all players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find the original patch notes/changelog, but from the [Battlefield Wikia](http://battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Below_Radar):

> Below Radar is a permanent vehicle specialization introduced to Battlefield 4 **with the Community Operations expansion**, and is **enabled by default for all air vehicles**. It functions almost identically to its Battlefield 3 counterpart, but it is available by default and does not hinder Spotting. Below Radar will protect against weapon locks from all anti-air vehicle missiles, including those from Mobile Anti-Air vehicles.
>
> Below Radar is automatically activated once the aircraft is below 25 meters in all Helicopters and below 50 meters in all Jets. [...]